# How to pass user data from the view to controller and return a roman numeral

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a web app in MVC that when a user enters a number in converts it to a roman numeral. I have the conversion method done and a basic view page. I am struggling with getting the inputted data in httppost action result method and then running it through the conversion method.

here is my controller so far:

```
public class ConvertController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
    {            
        
    }

    public void OnConvertClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Button clicked
        try
        {
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(myTextBox.Text);//Convert to number
            string romanNumber = ToRomanNumber(number);//Get roman number
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //The user input was not a number...
            myTextBox.Text = "Error";
        }
    }

    public string ToRomanNumber(int num)
    {
        var listOfNum = new List<int>() { 1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1 };
        var listOfRoman = new List<string>() { "M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I" };


        var numToRoman = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfNum.Count; i++)
        {
            while (num >= listOfNum[i])
            {
                numToRoman += listOfRoman[i];
                num -= listOfNum[i];
            }
        }
        return numToRoman;
    }

}
```

Here is my view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Numeral Converter</h2>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Convert numbers to roman numerals</legend>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "ConvertController",
                            new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ConversionDeatils" }))
    {
        <div id="divInterestDeatils"></div>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.Label("Enter Number to Convert")
                @Html.TextBox("myTextBox.Text")
            </li>

        </ol>
        <button>Convert</button>
    }
</fieldset>
```

Comment: u need to use a `type='submit'` button

Comment: Thanks would this work? <input id="Submit" type="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("OnConvertClicked", "ConvertController") + "'");" />

Comment: no need `onclick` and u need to call OnConvertClicked from [httppost] method

Comment: ok so i don't need this then  public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
    {            
        
    }

Comment: i will try to write one sample answer

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public string myNumber{ get; set; }
}
```

Change your view to something like this

```
@model MyViewModel 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Numeral Converter</h2>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Convert numbers to roman numerals</legend>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "ConvertController",
         new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ConversionDeatils" }))
    {
        <div id="divInterestDeatils"></div>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.Label("Enter Number to Convert")
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.myNumber)
            </li>

        </ol>
        <button id="Submit" type="Submit" value="Convert"></button> 
    }
</fieldset>
```

And your controller to

```
public class ConvertController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyViewModel myv = new MyViewModel();
        return View(myv);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
    {
        MyViewModel myv = new MyViewModel();
        decimal number = Convert.ToDecimal(form["myNumber"].ToString());
        myv.myNumber = ToRomanNumber(number);
        return View(myv);
    }


    public string ToRomanNumber(decimal num)
    {
        var listOfNum = new List<int>() { 1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1 };
        var listOfRoman = new List<string>() { "M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I" };


        var numToRoman = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfNum.Count; i++)
        {
            while (num >= listOfNum[i])
            {
                numToRoman += listOfRoman[i];
                num -= listOfNum[i];
            }
        }
        return numToRoman;
    }
}
```

Try this, and `@model MyViewModel`  here you may want to change according to your view model position

Comment: thanks, there is an error  at this line myv.myNumber = ToRomanNumber(number); (number) part says can not convert from decimal to int

Comment: try changing `ToRomanNumber(int num)` to `ToRomanNumber(decimal num)` and `var numToRoman = "";` to `var numToRoman = 0;`

Comment: or if you are sure only integer will be entered, change `decimal number = Convert.ToDecimal(form["myTextBox"].ToString());` into `int number = Convert.ToInt32(form["myTextBox"].ToString());`

Comment: error with this line decimal number = Convert.ToDecimal(form["myTextBox"].ToString()); says object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: i am sorry, i forgot to change the text box name, change `myTextBox` into the name of ur text box, `myNumber`